# Delete XML node that contains a certain value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath, linq-to-xml

Here is the xml structure.
I am trying to delete each Status node where State contains the word failed.
What is the best way to remove these?

```
<Stats>
    <Status>
        <Desc>something here</Desc>
        <State>pending - ok</State>
    </Status>
    <Status>
        <Desc>something here</Desc>
        <State>failed</State>
    </Status>
</Stats>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Main()
{   
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(@"<Stats>
    <Status>
        <Desc>something here</Desc>
        <State>pending - ok</State>
    </Status>
    <Status>
        <Desc>something here</Desc>
        <State>failed</State>
    </Status>
</Stats>");

    xml.Descendants("State").Where (x => x.Value.Contains("fail")).Ancestors("Status").Remove();
    Console.WriteLine(xml.ToString());  
}
```

Parse will load the xml in-memory, Load is used for loading it from a stream or via I/O means.

@Gregory Pilar's answer heavily influenced this answer; I believe he wrote that from memory, the snippet I provided was testing via LinqPad and returns expected results.

Comment: Thanks I have the issues sorted

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to XMl, to do the job

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);

xdoc.Descendants("Status")
.Where(os => (int)os.Attribute("State") == "failed")
.Remove();

xdoc.Save(path_to_xml);
```

Comment: it doesn't like the int being compared to a string. I changed it as follows but getting a null reference error: .Where(os => os.Attribute(key).Value.ToLower().Contains(value))

Answer (score 0):

```
xDoc.Descendants("Status").Where(status => status.Element("State").Value.ToLower().Contains("fail")).Remove();
```